# asterisk in arithmetic output

Tags: java, android

When computing 2 doubles, 1/81 on the android platform, 0.01234567* was returned. What does the asterisk mean and how can I avoid such an output?

```
a=Double.parseDouble(subexp.substring(ss, i));
b=Double.parseDouble(subexp.substring(i+1, se+1));

subexp=subexp.substring(0,ss).concat(Double.toString(a/b))
.concat(subexp.substring(se+1,subexp.length()));
```

so basically the piece of offending code is above, with the following values grabbed from the debugger:

```
subexp="1+1/81" (before code)
"1+0.01234567*" (after code) 

ss=2, se=5, i=3, a=1.0, b=81.0
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of how you are calculating and printing out your value?

Comment: Is there a missing zero after the point?

Comment: According to the [Android site](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)  * is used to format values.  Are you using a `NumberFormat`ter anywhere in your code?

Comment: 1.5/81 is normal but 1.1/81 gives 0.0135) and 1/81.1 gives 0.012330456226) strangely enough. I have not used a number formatter.

Comment: so I created a test application and set the content view to a textview whose sole purpose was to print out 1/81.0 and I got the same result as my original post. But when I compiled a java program outside of Android printing out the value of 1.0/81 I got a normal value. Does anyone know why? or perhaps a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Not to be a smartass, but if you just don't want the asterisk, try this immediately before you output your string:

```
subexp = subexp.replaceAll("\\*", "");
```

If your result requires something more elaborate than this, please provide more information and/or more complete source code, and I'll try to adapt my answer.

I made a simple project to test your code as posted. I printed the string out in the console as well as putting it in a TextView. In both places I get "1+0.012345689012345678", so I can't seem to replicate your results with the asterisk. Perhaps the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with my java installation or my program since I still got the same result with a plain app printing the numbers. I think it must have something to do with my computer or the android installation. 

The strange thing is after computing with 1+1/81, the numbers come out nicely so I guess I can manually change the output without giving up those numbers after the asterisk. 

Anyway, thanks for the reply.